# How to find exact matches between strings in sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text, full-text-search

I have two lists composed of sublists, something like:

```
 conopt = [["element1","element2"],["bla"]] 
 mat = [["element1","elementA"],["bla & etc"]]
```

From that data I want to fill a matrix with dimensions len(conopt) x len(mat). Since python by default doesn't have a  matrix I'll use another list with sublists:

```
finalmat = [ ["-","X",...,"X"],[...]]
```

I want `finalmat` to have an "X" where there is a full match (when a subelement of conopt matches a subelement of mat) and a "-" where there isn't. However I only care about the first full match for each sublist. If a sublist of conopt has 1 or more matches on a sublist of mat, the result should be the same, only one "X".

I've tried the following:

```
for i in mat:
    for j in conopt:
         for item in j:
             if item in i:
                 finalmat[mat.index(i)][conopt.index(j)] = "X"
```

However the result is not correct, because I've manually checked some data points and it doesn't give the correct result.

---

some extra (less important) info:

- the string elements are composed of letters, numbers, spaces (only spaces between words) and "#&" characters.
- the sublists have an arbitrary number of strings.
- this data comes from an excel file. I've manually extracted and modified it to match the python syntax.
- the output (finalmat) is going back to excel. I'm doing this step manually because this is an one off task and I don't want to complicate my code even more.

Comment: Have you tried out [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) built-in function of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mat.index(i)` and `conopt.index(j)` will not find `i` and `j` in **sublists**. I suggest using `enumerate`. Also make sure you correctly initialize `finalmat`.

```
finalmat = [ [ "-" for j in range(len(conopt) ] for i in range(len(mat)) ]
for indexmat, itemmat in enumerate(mat):
    for indexconopt, itemconopt in enumerate(conopt):
         for item in itemconopt:
             if item in itemmat:
                 finalmat[indexmat][indexconopt] = "X"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your code works perfectly. Do you know by any chance any course or book in which they explain this kind of functions and solve similar problems? I've done many python courses but they only teach basic concepts and don't enter in some other more complicated functions or ways of solving problems.